# Adding class to a div being collided

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

http://output.jsbin.com/kulobolutu/

This link contains the output of my code.
I have some divs where one div is draggable. You can drag that and collide it with another one. So I want the collided div to move ahead a little in such a way that it does not get out of the screen and adjust itself smoothly to another position.
Please help me in this case, i am badly stuck in this task.
Thanks in advance.

```
var overlaps = (function () {
    function getPositions( elem ) {
        var pos, width, height;
        pos = $( elem ).position();
        width = $( elem ).width();
        height = $( elem ).height();
        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
    }

    function comparePositions( p1, p2 ) {
        var r1, r2;
        r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
        r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
        return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    }

    return function ( a, b ) {
        var pos1 = getPositions( a ),
            pos2 = getPositions( b );
        return comparePositions( pos1[0], pos2[0] ) && comparePositions( pos1[1], pos2[1] );
    };
})();

function m() {
    var area = $( '#area' )[0],
        box = $( '#box0' )[0],
        html;

    html = $( area ).children().not( box ).map( function ( i ) {
      return '<p>Red box + Box ' + ( i + 1 ) + ' = ' + overlaps( box, this ) + '</p>';
    }).get().join( '' );

    $( '#result' ).html( html );


}

$('#box0').draggable({
  drag: function(){
    m();
  }
});
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for live working demo, click [here](http://output.jsbin.com/xiponuloxa/)

Use this javascript and css and it works

```
var overlaps = (function () {
    function getPositions( elem ) {
        var pos, width, height;
        pos = $( elem ).position();
        width = $( elem ).width();
        height = $( elem ).height();
        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
    }

    function comparePositions( p1, p2 ) {
        var r1, r2;
        r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
        r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
        return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    }

    return function ( a, b ) {
        var pos1 = getPositions( a ),
            pos2 = getPositions( b );
        return comparePositions( pos1[0], pos2[0] ) && comparePositions( pos1[1], pos2[1] );
    };
})();

function m() {
    var area = $( '#area' )[0],
        box = $( '#box0' )[0],
        html;

    html = $( area ).children().not( box ).map( function ( i ) {
    if(overlaps( box, this )){
      $("#box" + (i+1)).addClass("overlapped"); 
      }
      return '<p>Red box + Box ' + ( i + 1 ) + ' = ' + overlaps( box, this ) + '</p>';


    }).get().join( '' );

    $( '#result' ).html( html );


}

$('#box0').draggable({
  drag: function(){
    $(".overlapped").removeClass("overlapped");
    m();
  }
});
```

**Add these lines to Css**

```
.overlapped{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: that's very nice but please add the required one functionality please, so that it moves ahead and does not cross out the screen (instead of border),

Answer (score 0):

html5 and css3 have the div "transform" attribute witch can easily do what u need. here is some documentation https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: yes but i want to add the functionality in this code, i am trying but of no use till now

Comment: you can check my answer and the demo link in it